# Intel graphics(hd 4000) in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics

So I tried installing intel hd graphics 1.08 in ubuntu 14.04 but it says 'Distribution not supported'. I read up on the intel graphics forum that they have disabled it for ubuntu 14.04. So here is my question, should I upgrade to 14.10? Also I am not sure if I should upgrade using the software settings or reinstall my laptop with 14.10 altogether? Please bear in mind that I am an absolute newbie to ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're new to ubuntu I don't recommend upgrading till the next 16.04 LTS. I had many problems with 14.10, 15.04 is better, but the most stable release is 14.04. The graphics drives aren't that important. With 15.04 you get newer software and better look, so if you wanna upgrade, upgrade to 15.04, as it will get drivers in a couple of months if not earlier.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll heed to your advice and stick with 14.04 then. Out of curiosity, this doesn't concern the video performance of my laptop? I started worrying about this because I read in the intel forum that intel i915 performs better with the latest stack.

Comment: While I can't claim that, I'm pretty sure that you won't notice the difference. You can clone your drive and try it :)